# Restrict keyof 'Type' according to return type

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints, typescript-typings

How can I restrict the keys of an object to only those that return a certain type?

In the example below I want to ensure that the type of the property is a function, so that I can execute `obj[key]()`.

```
interface IObj{
  p1:string,
  p2:number,
  p3:()=>void
}

const obj:IObj = {
  p1:'str',
  p2:5,
  p3:()=>void 0
}

function fun<TKey extends keyof IObj>(key: IObj[TKey] extends ()=>void? TKey:never){
  const p = obj[key]
  p(); // This expression is not callable.
       // Not all constituents of type 'string | number | (() => void)' are callable.
       // Type 'string' has no call signatures.(2349)
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArA3gWAChlkAHARgC4BnMKUAcwBoiTSAmSkAVwFtNoLYmQDMlABQBKALwA%20AG4B7YABMiAXyJEEikLWSKclDDmTTkBYRUoByWlBtC2nAKxPREmQuUrkABg0tQhhuEAQwYF1kEJAAHgAVAGkIAE9kCAAPSBAVamQAa1TFGDQsbFlxQpTKUpwAbSTUgF10rIgcvKk5JVUAfmRG6pAIeWhJSxIdPTAyMwN6qqbWMikAbg0gA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the type to property name/never and then index into it, you have half of that already:

```
type FunctionKeys = {
    [K in keyof IObj]: IObj[K] extends () => void ? K : never
}[keyof IObj]; // <-

function fun(key: FunctionKeys) {
    const p = obj[key];
    p();
}
```

The indexing will perform a union over all the types of the properties and `A | never` is just `A`.

(Extracted the type because it's so long. Maybe there is a more elegant method.)

Comment: And if `IObj` is not known yet as in:
[Call method by name inside generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64500298/4233401)