# Call method by name inside generic function

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints, typescript-typings

[Related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64484348/4233401)

[Partial solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64484812/4233401)

I want to generalize the situation described here: [Restrict keyof 'Type' according to return type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64484348/4233401)

So I will have a function like the one below (*genericFunction*) where I don't know the `obj` type yet, but I want to make sure that the `obj[key]` can only be of a specific type.

```
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880555/4233401
type Identical<T, TTest, TTrue, TFalse> = (<U extends T>(
  o: U
) => void) extends <U extends TTest>(o: U) => void
  ? TTrue
  : TFalse;

type KeyWithValueOfType<THost, TValueType> = {
  [K in keyof THost]: Identical<THost[K], TValueType, K, never>;
  // [K in keyof THost]: THost[K] extends TValueType ? K : never;
}[keyof THost];

function genericFunction<T>(
  obj: T,
  methodName: KeyWithValueOfType<T, () => void>
): void {
  const method = obj[methodName];
  // How can I guarantee that method is callable?
  // Or that it is the type that I restricted at KeyWithValueOfType <THost, TValueType>
  
  method(); // This expression is not callable.
  //   Type 'unknown' has no call signatures.
}

type TTypeMethod = KeyWithValueOfType<IType, () => void>; // = "function" | "method"
 
genericFunction({} as IType, 'f'); // ok
genericFunction({} as IType, 'm'); // ok
genericFunction({} as IType, 'p'); // ok
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQgEAsBdIBwZwFwjpAhgYwNYHsBuBTAJwDMAbbAdwDp1sBbYVYAVgA52AGZ74AFgCYAzIN4cAjAChIATxj5QASQAm%20AHaQAlulSkAPABUANKH378KY6cIBXfJYBiOuPgB8oALygAFLoCqofAAPSDUlOBMXLwlQUGwEUF8JAEoPN1xsDSUUoJDVMNA-AODQ8NNzSEi4hJT3NIylaNAAfhN9G3xG%20P1HUmcAbglBmTlQAGl8aQB1DUhwADUdWwB5Yn1ZfAMACWwLEwXSWzW5N08Ab0aAbVHQDVVQTAnsYhNtlABdeOU1TW09fVfIFc3pZ9od1sZRsZVPgCIQXAMYmArjc7g9pE8XjtIB9MSggUVcvl9KD8Ed5C1rvFobCBgBfC5ojH-LFvAaDW4hEgYeQKMmgc4xYjxLw1OqZBGgOjC0WgdLixowKnWOgAIyIdKG61a6wAsvhZtglB4xhNprMSSsybpeeDvDK5Up4aAwJ4AETEayqdCabCqV2gAA%20oFddH14ENrsGHq9PruAHM1EQtPZPd6NL6DJFGtgVQArLqGRqhg1KAByqFD8XGUxm80W%20Et6wMxhFqVl9RcyXiDv5jVoqhQkrDhuNOdzF2L4bLFfwrOdwFA2wooG0dwUoDj1lQhFQ6nw8lmqEgQ5LN3Cv1IqBVpHwTSLw6UIr685M4A04SCMEI5jg6bu79AVRsGPC8rxvKhGjAGI%20QAck9TAgIoVQYIgVBwiAlcdFIUBfzjVQj2sb84Ag2ko1TWMcLkdANGIZNyL-KIYjHT4yULGJJ0NctKxNGtzXrRs5GtVi7TbB1OySbt6l7GJ%200HDijU8McJwfLjZ2fe8SyfF85BIfBvQkUiJATaFCDomMGNOWlQDQxRhJg4gYKSZ8wB04g9MgIzE1M9AU3M30vEs6zwhtORjBguhHOchdXPczyTLMtN-MCmyQrsUAYJgSLtKINzvSAA)

Comment: Probably a limitation of how types with generics get resolved, there might not be much you can do here except ignoring the error (preferably `@ts-except-error` as this might work at some point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your `genericFunction` is dependent on the type of the object `T`.  We can flip it around and make it dependent on the type of the key instead.

We use a helper utility type that defines an object for which all keys assignable to `Key` have a value that is assignable to `Value`.

```
export type HasProperty<Key extends keyof any, Value> = {
  [K in Key]: Value;
}
```

Now we make our `genericFunction` dependent on a key `K extends keyof any`.  The `methodName` is of type `K` and the object is an object which has a parameterless `void` function for every `K` key.

```
function genericFunction<K extends keyof any>(
  obj: HasProperty<K, () => void>,
  methodName: K
): void {
  const method = obj[methodName];
  method();
}
```

This works as expected, giving us an error if the object type doesn't have a function as the property in `methodName`.

```
genericFunction({} as IType, 'f'); // ok
genericFunction({} as IType, 'm'); // ok
genericFunction({} as IType, 'p'); // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcASBDAzgBShFWRAHgGlhE5QZgA7AEyzgGsKIAzODWxAGjgBqGADYBXYAD44AXjgBvAFBw4AbVJwAlrTjlEAXQBcgkeIDcCgL4KFWmlHYYAxqgCSAFWSpFy9kYAUAJQyUgBuEBr05soAtv5B0qHhkUpwYEa0otEARsBQ5lYK7KK0jjAaENoA5nS5Go4AYsWl5bRkVCA0DEysiBxcPBJ%20KRBZAFZGmLj4hEhk-IHBcGERErwp0cAwABYQ9AByGBtGpAoBRsv08imOFVjwG9u7MnAjoyoPO-uHwHpRcB%207QL5azVWi1BpNMoVPxyCxcJjuTz8ADk7GRAVMcAA9FiXswFKDwY0SlDaDC4dg4IiUCjoujMTi8QSalA6sTmtDYfCqR4aXBkWB6djcbl8FAgA)